# How to put comments in Django templates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-comments

I would like to comment this with a line:

```
{% if something.property %}
    <table>
        <tr>...



{% # this is a comment %}
{% if something.property %}
    <table>
        <tr>...
```

Answer (score 430, accepted):

As answer by Miles, `{% comment %}...{% endcomment %}` is used for multi-line comments, but you can also comment out text on the same line like this:

```
{# some text #}
```

Comment: True, but if you have an `{% extends "file.html" %}` tag you should put that on the very top of the template file even before the `{% comment %}`...`{% endcomment %}`, otherwise you'll get an `<ExtendsNode: extends "file.html"> must be the first tag in the template` error. I am saying that in case someone wants to place the multi-line comments on the top of the template.

Answer (score 171):

Comment tags are documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-comment

```
{% comment %} this is a comment {% endcomment %}
```

---

Single line comments are documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/#comments

```
{# this won't be rendered #}
```

Answer (score 33):

Using the `{# #}` notation, like so:

```
{# Everything you see here is a comment. It won't show up in the HTML output. #}
```

Answer (score 9):

This way can be helpful if you want to comment some Django Template format Code.

`{#% include 'file.html' %#}` (Right Way)

Following code still executes if commented with HTML Comment.

`<!-- {% include 'file.html' %} -->` (Wrong Way)

Answer (score 7):

This is [**single-line comments**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#comments):

```
{# <p>This is comment</p> #}
```

This is [**multi-line comments**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#comment):

```
{% comment "This is an optional note for comments" %}
    <p>This is comment</p>
    <p>This is comment</p>
    <p>This is comment</p>
{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't work if you want to comment before `{% extends ... %}`
In this case better use

```
<!--
# comment 1
# comment 2
# comment 3
-->
```