# Commenting out HTML, CSS, Javascript Code Together

Tags: javascript, html, css, comments

I have the following code in a ***base.html*** file in a Django project's header area.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'create' %}"><span class="oi oi-plus"></span></a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}" onclick="">Logout</a>
  <form id="logout" method="POST" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" />
  </form>
  {% else %}
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
  {% endif %}
```

I try to comment out the Javascript area "{% url 'create' %}" but it is not working (the error appears because the 'create' code chunks don't yet exists):

```
 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/*{% url 'create' %}*/"><span class="oi oi-plus"></span></a>

 <!-- <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'create' %}"><span class="oi oi-plus"></span></a> -->

 <!-- <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/*{% url 'create' %}*/"><span class="oi oi-plus"></span></a> -->
```

When I delete the whole line the error disappears. What I would be interested is how to keep it as a comment so later on when I implement that area I can uncomment it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put comments in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719915/how-to-put-comments-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two solutions.

For a code block use:

```
{% comment %}...{% endcomment %}
```

For single line you can use this:

```
{# some text #}
```

Comment: @Laif, haha I was confused why my edit didn't pull through. =") Sorry I pushed the wrong button and wanted to edit my own question.

Comment: That's pretty funny, no worries.